# What exactly does the stop button in R do?

Tags: r

Does the stop button (or esc key) in R stop a loop after a completion?

e.g.:

```
x=1:100
i=2
repeat{
     x[i]=x[i]+3
     x[i-1]=x[i]+1
     i=i+1
     if(i>100){break}
}
```

and I hit stop before the loop ends... will the loop break at the end of a repeat, or will it break in the middle?

Does anyone know where to find documentation on this stop button?

Thanks

Comment: I would just try this out and see!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "stop button" is actually a GUI feature so its documentation should be consulted. The keyboard ctrl-C or 'esc-key' should do the same. The commentary I have seen is rather non-committal about how soon an interrupt will be handled. It says something like: "well written code will handle interrupts promptly."

```
> x=1:1000000
> i=2
> repeat{
+      x[i]=x[i]+3
+      x[i-1]=x[i]+1
+      i=i+1
+      if(i>length(x)){break} } # esc key hit promptly
> i
[1] 15128
```

You should read the help page for:

```
?conditions
```

The 'R for Mac OS X FAQ' says: "However, if the executed code does not check for interrupts (using `R_CheckUserInterrupt') there may be no way of stopping R. In that case it may be worth alerting the maintainer of the package to allow interruption (if appropriate)."

This search will let you page through postings to R-devel that mention that internal mechanism by name: http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.r-project+R_CheckUserInterrupt

Comment: It’s roughly eight years since I wrote this and I just got the checkmark. :-)